# How do I get an emission effect with a transparent BSDF material?

Tags: transparency, emission

I have the following circle with rings which I've successfully made transparent for the gaps. However, I'm having trouble getting the blue parts to have an emission effect. I'm completely lost and have tried mixing the Transparent BSDF with an emission node but it's not working as expected

[image: Rings with Transparent Gaps]

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out:

[image]

1. I've got to get the Color Ramp as a Fac to the Mix Shader
2. The emission and the transparent BSDF have to be both shaders

Comment: or like this as well, the colorramp going into emission is basically useless in my answer but I left it there anyway... it will have same result if you left it out

Comment: I'm not sure if you did this deliberately (since it seems you're quite new to this because this is a very basic material setup, no offense), but using the _Color Ramp_ with blue and white color instead of black and white is not necessary (because the _Emission_ shader is blue) and maybe even not what you want. Because the _Fac_ input converts the color from the ramp into greyscale, which means your blue is some light grey with a value of something like 0.233, so the emissive part is almost 77% transparent (which isn't so obvious because of the high strength). If that's what you wanted, fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need:
[image]

Just use the same color ramp twice, use math node to control the emission strength and mix it in mixshader

[image]

Comment: I would eliminate the _Color Ramp_ for the _Emission_ shader because: first of all it's not necessary and for beginners it might give the impression it is needed for this to work properly. Secondly, if by accident the sliders are changed a little on one of the ramps this might e.g. result in an unwanted black opaque area where it's supposed to be transparent or emissive. Thirdly, but this is a minor negligible issue in this case: the more nodes are contributing to a material, the more time it needs to be rendered. But of course this makes no noticeable difference in this case.

Comment: The reason for that color ramp is due to me making it based on his question and I included it there even though it is not needed at all as I stated in the comment of his answer

Comment: Yeah, I read that - but even he figured out he doesn't need two color ramps. Maybe that's just me, I'm trying to give answers that teach how to do it simpler or better if there is a way to do it more efficient. Sorry, don't mean to be rude, I just don't understand why not point into a better direction instead of taking a detour only to keep the original.